# Sequence Analysis and Predicting the Next Label

Tags: machine-learning, classification, sequence-analysis

I have recorded a dataset of about 1000 entries in the following format.

```
TimeStamp  | Action  | UserId
2015-02-05 | Action1 | XXX
2015-02-06 | Action2 | YYY
2015-02-07 | Action2 | XXX
...
```

I try to forecast future `Actions` for specific users based on the `Users` history in the dataset. Do you have some ideas on which algorithms I should look at, as I am quite new to this field.

EDIT

A main goal is to find periodic patterns (based on the timestamp) for single users and actions. The history of a user should be analyzed over time to find peaks for specific actions.

Comment: I have updated the question with the goal (to find periodic patterns)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Still, it's too broad a topic for a stack overflow question! Google *predicting user behavior* to see the tip of the iceberg.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Naive Bayes for classifying the Action for user, where you would need to use Action as a Label (class) of Naive Bayes and UserId and/or timeStamp as the independent variables